# How do I hide the popup windows that appear from markers using the google map api?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps

I have popup windows with the name and the address of the location coming up with when you click on the map marker but I want to hide the window when I click on it again.
I know I need to do some sort of on click hide function but I really have no idea, can someone help me out please? 
  I added the little snippet on the bottom but it doesn't work. Should I use an if else statement?

Javascript

```
 function myMap() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.1856, 33.3823),
        zoom: 10,
    };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

// Add markers


        addMarker({
            coords: {
                lat: 35.192518,
                lng: 32.994273
            },
            content: '<h3 style="font-weight: bold;">GURDAL BAHAR</h3> <h3>IMAJ MUSIC ( MYCOM İLETİŞİM)</h3> <h4>3927277774</h4><h6>TURKCELL BAYI MY COM, NUMARA 1, Gemikonağı - GÜZELYURT<h6>'
        });


        //check content





        //Add marker function

        function addMarker(props) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: props.coords,
                map: map,
     //      icon:props.iconImage
            });


            if (props.content) {
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: props.content
                });

                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });


                 marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infoWindow.close(map, marker);
                });

            }

        }
    }
```

```
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.close(map, marker);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently both the open and close click listeners run when the marker is clicked (so it runs `infoWindow.open()` then `infoWindow.close()` and the `infoWindow` stays closed).

This works for me:

```
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    // if infoWindow not open, open it
    if (infoWindow.getMap() == null)
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    else // if infoWindow open, close it
      infoWindow.close();
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zxpk4odt/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function myMap() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.1856, 33.3823),
    zoom: 10,
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  // Add markers
  addMarker({
    coords: {
      lat: 35.192518,
      lng: 32.994273
    },
    content: '<h3 style="font-weight: bold;">GURDAL BAHAR</h3> <h3>IMAJ MUSIC ( MYCOM İLETİŞİM)</h3> <h4>3927277774</h4><h6>TURKCELL BAYI MY COM, NUMARA 1, Gemikonağı - GÜZELYURT<h6>'
  });
  //check content
  //Add marker function

  function addMarker(props) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: props.coords,
      map: map,
      //      icon:props.iconImage
    });

    if (props.content) {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: props.content
      });

      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        if (infoWindow.getMap() == null)
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        else
          infoWindow.close();
      });
    }

  }
}
```

```css
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="googleMap"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=myMap">


</script>
```